# Returning Excel file in POST request response and Downloading it on client side using Angular 5

Tags: angular, spring-boot, excel-2010

I need to create an excel file(.xlsx) using Spring boot and send it in response to a POST call done by the Angular Front End and then handle the response on the client side by straight away downloading the file.

How do I achieve this?

Or is it better to send JSON and use something like XLSX on the Angular side to generate the excel file ?

**Edit 1:**

So I am able to create an excel file and send it as a byteArray in response like so:

```
@PostMapping("/excel")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> fetchFile(@RequestBody Employee employee) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = excelService.getExcelSheet();
    byte[] response = outputStream.toByteArray();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Content-Disposition"));
    headers.set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=employee.xlsx");
    headers.setAccessControlExposeHeaders(Collections.singletonList("Content-Type"));
    headers.set("Content-Type","application/vnd.ms-excel");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Stuff is great when using postman to download the file. 
But how do I consume this on the Angular front and download the file as an .xlsx file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this using apache poi library if you are new at this you can find a good tutorial on this in here:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

Comment: ok so I am able to send the excel file in response as a byteArray. How do I consume the byteArray on my Angular app and download it as an .xlsx file ?

Comment: for more on this you can read this tutorial: http://oppalove.com/2016/02/16/download-excel-file-using-angular-js/?i=1